# ASP.NET Menu Control - Cant't click menu items on remote server

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, menu, controls, compatibility

ASP.NET control is working fine on development environment, but after going to production remote server it does not allow to click menu item link.

I've noticed, that the problem is only in IE (9). On Chrome and Fireworks it's working fine. It’s also OK in IE compatibility mode, but who would go for that… ;)

Normally I would do some changes in CSS, but on local machine with the same browser it is working just fine.

Should I be looking for new menu control or starting to write new one? What is Your opinion? Had similar problems?

Thanks in advance for Your help.